# Magento2 - setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, setup-upgrade, bin-magento

I have been working in a project with some custom code... this is our first "medium" Magento 2 project, so (as all people here I think) every day we learn new things, and we have to change the way to deal with this new Magento version

The reason for this question is asking about the command `setup:di:compile`

I've been using it since the first day with Magento 2, as bin/magento asks for it after every `setup:upgrade`, with message *"Please re-run Magento compile command"*

Well... I have found executing `setup:di:compile` breaks product view page in this project, with a totally ambiguous Fatal Error. I've spent whole working days trying to debug it and testing with code changes with zero result

Today, I have discovered that if I omit that command then all works like a charm, **even in production mode**

So, the question is... what exactly does that `setup:di:compile` command? Is it required? Just recommended? Or it is some deprecated command, which is not needed to be executed?

**UPDATE**

As some users have required, this is the Fatal Error I was referring

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot instantiate abstract class
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView in
>   ***/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93

I've searched for any custom block using Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView but I've found it only in layout files, it is not present in any block class constructor

What I can't understand is: why Magento is throwing this Fatal Error with compiled code, but it works like a charm without compiled code

Comment: can you confirm that 'setup:di:compile' causes the product view error in development mode too?

Comment: yes, Fatal Error occurs in both modes

Comment: Can you post the "totally ambiguous Fatal Error"?

Comment: I have updated the question with error. Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The command `setup:di:compile` command generates the contents of the `var/di` folder in Magento <2.2 and `generated`  for Magento >= 2.2

According to Magento, this serves the following purpose:

- Application code generation (factories, proxies, and so on)
- Area configuration aggregation (that is, optimized dependency injection
  configurations per area)
- Interceptor generation (that is, optimized
  code generation of interceptors)
- Interception cache generation
- Repositories code generation (that is, generated code for APIs)
- Service data attributes generation (that is, generated extension
  classes for data objects)

Source (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html)

However, when you place Magento in production mode, without compilation it indeed still works. So according to the Magento docs this is more an optimization step *(that is, optimized code generation of interceptors)*

When we have errors in the `setup:di:compile` command, this is mostly because of errors in one of the constructors of custom php classes.

Comment: Thanks! So, it is totally optional... Just one point, so it is more clear to me. In our case, setup:di: compile does not throw any error, command ends ok. It is when browsing the site, after command has finished, when Fatal Error is fired, in product view pages

Comment: Maybe you can post the error? That would make thing more clear.

Comment: I have updated the question with error. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

It's not mandatory to run `setup:di:compile` command everytime but if you have done any code change specially with factory methods ,proxy, add plugins or any code compilation then you must need to run this command.

> More Details

`magento setup:di:compile` in order to generate necessary files. Both options ends up with generating classes in `MAGENTO_ROOT/var/generation directory` (or `/generated` if Magento 2.2+).

**What classes are generated?**

1. Factories
2. Proxies
3. Plugins

**Factories**

Factories are used to instantiate objects that can not be injected automatically.  For example, a product object has to be loaded from the database, but dependency injection container doesn’t have enough information to create this object. That’s why we use factories.

**Proxies**

Magento 2 uses constructor injection in which all dependencies are required. You cannot instantiate an object without passing all dependencies. What if you’d like to have optional dependencies? That’s why proxies exist.

**Plugins (Interceptors)**

Simply put, plugins are the primary customization mechanisms for Magento 2. No more class rewrites. It allows you to hook in and do something before, after or around any public method of the application.

**when you run setup:di:compile command it do below things**

Code compilation consists of all of the following in no particular order:

- Application code generation (factories, proxies, and so on)
- Area configuration aggregation (that is, optimized dependency
  injection configurations per area)
- Interceptor generation (that is, optimized code generation of
  interceptors)
- Interception cache generation Repositories code generation (that is,
  generated code for APIs)
- Service data attributes generation (that is, generated extension
  classes for data objects)

**Refer this answer for when we should run which  commands: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758**

Comment: Thanks! So, it is totally optional... Just one point, so it is more clear to me. In our case, setup:di: compile does not throw any error, command ends ok. It is when browsing the site, after command has finished, when Fatal Error is fired, in product view pages... so I don't really understand why not compiled code works nice but when compiling then Fatal Error happens

Comment: This can happen if your sub-class added new dependencies after the existing optional dependencies of the parent class. You can fix this by moving any new required parameter up above the optional ones.

Comment: @PrincePatel Please can you answer this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279795/why-i-still-need-to-run-setupdicompile-in-developer-mode

Comment: I often added plugins and I never had to run setup:di:compile after it. It worked without (developer mode)

Answer (score 3):

Magento will still run in production and dev without the di:compile command. It will actually compile the Interceptors as it needs to and store the in the `generated` folder.

Even if it works, that does not mean you should skip this step! In fact, when this is ran, magento also checks for duplicated injections, dependency loops and other fundamental steps that will make your site more stable and less likely to crash and !die.

I strongly believe that that error is due to the use of a class that Magento can't compile due to some wrong constructor argument.

The error you posted is pretty vague, but I believe you have a class that extends the `AbstractView` class, 99% it's a block somewhere in your custom modules that **does not pass the correct arguments to the `parent::__construct()` method**. Hence when instantiated it fails.

Note that **all** blocks extend the AbstractView class so you'll have to execute the compile command with `xdebug` on and set a log at look at the stack trace to see what class called it last before it failed.

The fact that the site runs without that error means that you're **not** actually using the *corrupted* block anywhere on your page, but Magento will still try to compile it when running the `compile` command, hence it fails.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer an older question like this, with other validated answers... In fact, I resolved this by fixing that wrong blocks in custom layouts, as you have pointed