# Magento 2: When should I run which commands?

Tags: magento2, command-line

I have been working with **Magento 2** for 2 months now. I realized that I am using `bin/magento setup:upgrade` way too much. I think I do not know when I **have to** run that command.

Here are the situations that I run the aforementioned command.

- When I create a new Module,
- When I add something to Setup directory,
- When I edit `etc/module.xml`,
- When I edit `etc/di.xml`,
- When I edit `etc/webapi.xml`,
- When I edit `etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

**Question:** In which situations is it absolutely necessary to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command?

(*The reason I am asking is that it takes some time finish that command. I believe that it can really improve the productivity if I stop using it unnecessarily.*)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**You only need to run `setup:upgrade` command**

**1. When you made changes in Setup script(InstallData, InstallSchema,

UpgradeData, UpgradeSchema, ...)**

**2. If you install Magento first time.**

**3. At the time of new module installation**

**4. After upgrade magento version.**

> **What will do `setup:upgrade` command**

**1)** Check module version in `setup_module` table

**2)** If version not available or new version added in module.xml, It will run setup script and add latest version number in table

If you made changes in **HTML, CSS, JS, ...** files you need to delete particular changed files from `pub/static` folder or run this command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> **Short Form:** php bin/magento s:s:d

If you made changes like **add new dependency in __construct() or changes in `di.xml`**, you need to delete changed files from `var/generation` folder or run this command

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> **Short Form:** php bin/magento s:d:c

If you made changes in **admin configuration, layout xml, ui component, phtml, ...** files you need to only clean or flush cache

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> **Short Form:** php bin/magento c:f

**EDIT:**

**You can run cache flush by only typing `c:f` without using the full command `php bin/magento c:f`**

Answer (score 3):

1.When I create a new Module:

2.When I add something to Setup directory

3.When I edit etc/module.xml

```
php bin/magento module:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

4.When I edit etc/module.xml,

5.When I edit etc/di.xml,

6.When I edit etc/webapi.xml,

7.When I edit etc/adminhtml/system.xml
**for xml changes cache flush is more than enough:**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

css and js changes:
 -- flush cache and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: As far as I understand, `setup:upgrade` can be executed as an alternative to `module:enable`.

Comment: Are any scripts available combining these commands in 1?

Answer (score 2):

If you work with **developer mode** you don't need to `compil`e when you modify `xml`, you can make only a `setup:upgrade`.

And for others modifications as `css`, `phtml`, `js`, only `flush cache`, you needn't to **deploy static content**.

Comment: No, We don't need to run `setup:upgrade` for xml modification. For more details refer upper answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a bash file that could automate the process:

in your magento folder type 'vi magento_bash'
copy and paste the code below.
save file by escaping and :wq and enter
hope this helps.
Note: the below file takes only one command at a time.

```
#!/bin/sh

mainmenu()
{

echo 'Press 1 if you have created a new module'

echo 'Press 2 if you have changed HTML, CSS, JS..'

echo 'Press 3 if you have made changes like add new dependency in __construct() or changes in di.xml'

echo 'Press 4 if you have made changes like admin configuration, layout xml, ui component, phtml'

read -n 1 -p "Input Selection:" mainmenuinput

if [ "$mainmenuinput" = "1" ];
then
    cd src
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "2" ];
then
    cd src
    php bin/magento s:s:d en_AU en_US
elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "3" ];
then
    cd src
    php bin/magento setup:di:compile
elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "4" ];
then
    cd src
    php bin/magento cache:flush
else
    echo 'You have selected an invalid selection'
fi
}

mainmenu
```

Comment: en_AU en_US behind ssd command?

Answer (score 1):

Simply need to run bin/magento setup:upgrade **whenever you do modification on the database.**

For instance if you are creating attributes (programically), new modules, version upgrades etc.

So the basic rule to keep in mind is, if you know your code would do modifications on the database, then run the setup:upgrade command.

Comment: Does `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` make the setup CRON JOB obsolete? I am confused because it is logged here as a cronjob to run everye minute https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/module-man/compman-checklist.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are deploying your code manually. All the above suggested methods are good enough to save time.

If you have auto deployment through Jenkins or some other tools, you should run all the commands as the tool don't know what you did and which file was changed.