# Magento2 - override 3rd party module layout file in custom theme

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, dependency

We have a **custom theme** with some `layout / template` overrides

Now we have installed a **3rd party module**, which is overriding one of layout files in our custom theme. So, only module's override is being loaded

I suppose, we can deal with this, by defining that concrete layout override in a custom module (`instead of the custom theme approach`), and then define the **module dependencies** to load both layout overrides

Or is there a way to do that **without the need of declaring a new module**?

**UPDATE**

About [RishabhRkRai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/43064/rishabhrkrai) answer...

Let's say our custom theme is placed in folder `app/design/frontend/Sinapsis/projectname`

We had this layout override there:

```
app/design/frontend/Sinapsis/projectname/Magento_Multishipping/layout/multishipping_checkout_billing.xml
```

Now, we've installed a module which overrides that same layout file. The concrete module name is **Df_Checkout**, and problem is our layout override stopped working

I've tried, following the answer, moving our override to

```
app/design/frontend/Sinapsis/projectname/Df_Checkout/layout/multishipping_checkout_billing.xml
```

but only module's layout keeps loading

Comment: You can just create your module layout file inside theme and set your old layout changes to your new module layout file.

Comment: please note that if you changed your sequence you need to run bin/magento module:disable YOUR_MODULE, followed by bin/magento module:enable YOUR_MODULE to make sure Magento has updated the configuration load order (as seen in app/etc/config.php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your custom theme, follow this to override the layout file

> app/design/frontend/Theme_Vendor/Theme_Name/ThirdPartyVendor_ModuleName/layout/file_to_override.xml

After doing this, remove the static files and flush the cache

1. rm -rf pub/static/*
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. php bin/magento cache:flush

There is an alternate way, which may works for  you. You just need to create an custom module and inside **module.xml** add the dependency like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="2.1.7">
        <sequence>
            <module name="ThirdParty_ModuleName"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Now you have to override the xml file as

> app/code/Vendor/Module_Name/view/**Scope**/layout/file_to_override.xml

**Scope** can be either **frontend** or **adminhtml** (for backend)

Comment: You should not remove pub/static or static-content to overriding xml files. You only need clean or flush cache for this task. For more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Comment: Mmm... so it is same concept as overriding Magento modules files, is it? I think this does not work for me. 3rd party module continues loading its layout

Comment: @RaulSanchez I used this method to override 3rd party module and It's work for me.

Comment: I am going to update the question, so it is more clear

Comment: Am I the only one who got this working with `app/design/frontend/Theme_Vendor/Theme_Name/VendorName_ModuleName/layout/file_to_override.xml` instead of `app/design/frontend/Theme_Vendor/Theme_Name/VendorName/ModuleName/layout/file_to_override.xml`. It should be `VendorName_ModuleName` instead of `VendorName/ModuleName`

Comment: @AkashK., no, I also had to do it like this.

Answer (score 2):

As per Magento documentation you need to put the layout file under "layout/override/base". Try this example ( tested on Magento ver. 2.3.5)

<theme_dir>/Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/layout/override/base/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

will override

vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

Answer (score 1):

Please note that magento has 2 ways to customize layout.

**Extend layout**
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html

**Override layout** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Here are a few steps to make sure that your layout is extended correctly.

1. move layout in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Sinapsis/projectname/Df_Checkout/layout/multishipping_checkout_billing.xml

2. Check the layout and make sure that block names match.
3. Check the code in your Block. There are cases when the template was updated directly in the block code. In that way you need to extend the Block.