# Trying to override 3rd party vendor file

Tags: magento2.3, third-party-module

I've read over this page ( [Magento2 - override 3rd party module layout file in custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191015/magento2-override-3rd-party-module-layout-file-in-custom-theme) ) and I am still having an issue.

What I am trying to do is override the 2 files that vendor offers for the end user to download.  Which are sample.CSV and sample.XML file (Not to be confused with xml files within Magento).    File path to them is below. These files are basic formats a customer can use to upload bulk orders.

```
vendor/amasty/module-quick-order/Files/Samples/
                                               sample.csv
                                               sample.xml
```

I've tried placing 2 edited files into the file path to override the vendor 2 files.

```
app/frontend/OURCUSTOMTHEME/THETHEME/Amasty_QuickOrder/Files/Samples/
                                                                    sample.csv
                                                                    sample.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overwrite those files with theme and i guess the sample files are served with controller action.

Based on demo the URL is https://quick-order-for-magento-2.magento-demo.amasty.com/amasty_quickorder/file_sample/xml/

If you want to replace those files you can review related controller action and create plugin for or rewrite the same route in your custom extension

I'm not familiar with this extension and don't have source code of and cannot check. Maybe possible to replace those files in configuration. Please also check.

Links:

- [How to rewrite controller in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-rewrite-controller.html)
- [How to overwrite controller with plugin](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html#controller-override)