# Hide add to Compare in category page beside add to cart

Tags: category, compare

I have been able to remove every link to add to compare but I cant get the one away that is placed beside the add to cart button on the category page.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your extended **default.xml** file and Find it at your extended theme path

```
app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

To remove compare from listing Page add this line of code

```
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
```

This is how your default.xml will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>


        <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>   <!-- BLOCK Removed on Category page-->




    </body>
</page>
```

**Keep cache disabled** and run following commands if needed

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Tested and it works, should help you out as well

Comment: You need not run setup:upgrade or static-content:deploy for this task. Just need to clear or flush cache. For more details about when you should run which command prefer my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184921/magento-2-when-should-i-run-which-commands

Comment: I followed the instructions but it didnt help. 2 questions: Should I put default.xml in app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
or app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/templates/layout/default.xml and is it enought with a single line default.xml (<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>) or does it need additional code?

Comment: didn't get you , is compare link removed ?

Comment: I updated my comment.

Comment: put inside your  Magento_Theme/layout/

Comment: update code for default.xml in answer ...

Comment: It works now! Didnt need to run php commands, just flushed the cache in magento and browser. Thank you Manoj!

Comment: great ! your welcome