# Is there a fast way to flush cache and empty static folders using putty commands?

Tags: magento2, layout-update, less-css

Is there a fast way to flush cache and empty static folders using putty commands? I am in developer mode and sometimes I dont know what I need to do so that the site updates my edits. Can one combine commands in putty and run at once?

Comment: You can check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do to run all commands in one go.

Combine all your commands in a single line joining them with `&&` or `||`

If you want to flush cache `php bin/magento cache:flush` and remove static folders `rm -rf var/generation var/cache var/page_cache`, You can join these two commands in a single line,

```
php bin/magento cache:flush && rm -rf var/generation var/cache var/page_cache
```

You can add as many of commands joining with `&&` or `||`

[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13077311/1409718) [Reference2](https://www.howtogeek.com/269509/how-to-run-two-or-more-terminal-commands-at-once-in-linux/)