# Generation of var/cache/ var/generation and var/di folders Magento2

Tags: magento2, cache, code-generation

I have a very simple question. Which magento commands cause the removal of

```
var/cache/ 
var/generation/
var/di/
```

Folders and which bin/magento commands create them again.

Comment: You can prefer this answer for when you should run which commands: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`var/cache` is cleared by `php bin/magento cache:flush`. It rebuilds on the fly as data is cached by Magento (there's no command to rebuild, it just happens).

`var/di` and `var/generation` are cleared by `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, or manually (like executing `rm -rf var/di var/generation` from site root--be very careful with this!). You can rebuild them by running the command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`. If you are in non-production mode, you can leave them and Magento will rebuild the generated sources on the fly (but it'll be a little slower while that happens).

Answer (score 0):

must be `php bin/magento cache:flush`  command