# Although I use the correct namespace a wrong instance is passed to the constructor

Tags: magento2, blocks, di

I have a block php file.
Block File Code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SampleModule1\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Vendor\SampleModule1\Model\ResrouceModel\Item\Collection;
use Vendor\SampleModule1\Model\ResrouceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;

class Hello extends Template
{
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data =[]
    )
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Vendor\SampleModule1\Model\Item[]
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->collectionFactory->create()->getItems();
    }
}
```

When I try to see the view the error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: 
>       Argument 1 passed to Vendor\SampleModule1\Block\Hello::__construct() 
>       must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given ....

How is that possible ? ? ?

Comment: try to do di:compile

Comment: Did you try to remove `var/generation` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your code after you have done changes.

Please do

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. It wasn't mentioned at all in the tutorial.

Comment: Yes, they are not going to do that coz, they consider it as an "already knowing" fact (by every Magento developer). We all gone through this confusion and found out the answer ourself :)

Comment: but on every tutorial the commande chace:flush is used :) whatever ... just weird, thank you

Comment: it is for clearing the cache.. that step is also a MUST step and also considered as Magento trivia :). Always clear your cache and recompile after changes made while you are doing development.

Comment: @LachezarRaychev Check this answer for when you should run which commands: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Comment: @PrincePatel Yes, that's a nice reference point.