# Magento2: Change in di.xml

Tags: magento-2.1, di.xml

After making a change to `app/etc/di.xml`

Am I required to take some additional steps in order for the change to take effect?

Like **clean cache**, **deploy static files** or **compile code**?

Comment: yes sure, please run clean cache and deploy static files.

Comment: Why you modify here [app/etc/di.xml] ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to recompile after you have done some changes in `di.xml` file and then it's a good practice to remove cache too.

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

A [nice answer is here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/3535) for your reference. Hope it will give you a better idea.

Comment: @PrincePatel it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove  the folders inside the `var/` like

- generation
- cache
- page_cahce`apart from`.htaccess` file

Then run the command `php bin/magento c:f`,

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible through the Admin UI.

1. Go to: System > Cache Management
2. Check "Configuration" in the table
3. In the dropdown over the table choose "Refresh" and click "Submit".

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, it will clean all caches and remove generated folders as well.