# Why do i have to always run the commands to clean cache in Magento 2.1.8?

Tags: magento2, css, cache, cron, cookie

Whenever I make any change to CSS of my Magento store, it doesn't seem to be updated.

I also tried to clean the cache from the Magento admin dashboard but it didn't work.

**Now I always have to run the following commands via putty.**

1. sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. sudo php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
4. sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
5. sudo chmod -R 777 var

Server - EC2 (Amazon AWS)

**Please help!**

Comment: Refer this answer for when you should run which command: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's (unfortunately) the way Magento 2 works.

If you're in developer or default mode, you can Flush static files and refresh the cache from your admin (there are buttons for each in cache management).

But if you're in production, then you need to run

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But you need to be logged in as the owner of your server. In other words, don't log into CLI as root.

Since you are on shared hosting, you also shouldn't use **sudo** for this command, because that changes the ownership of all your static content files to the **root** user and then you can't load the website without giving 777 permissions on all the static files (which is something you definitely shouldn't do).

Also if you're in production, you need to run

> php bin/magento cache:flush

after static content is flushed.