# Magento 2: Is it required to compile after manual extension update?

Tags: magento2, extensions

Is it required to run setup:di:compile after manually sending extension update via FTP? Installation is in production mode.

Comment: Check this answer for when you should run which command: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for certain without knowing what the exact diff between the previously installed version and the updated version is.

However any change in constructor, method signatures or di configuration including plugins can trigger the need for a re-compile.

On the balance of probabilities I would say yes it's required.

Comment: Ok. So it is an extension specific or even update specific thing. Thank you!