# Inserting block with referenceContainer reorders existing elements

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, theme-overriding

I tried to insert an additional button on the **wishlist page**, but when I do that for some reason the order of all elements in a certain container gets reversed (that includes `<script>` elements!). What I did is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.wishlist.buttons">
            <block after="-"
                name="mycompany.blockname"
                class="MyCompany\ModulName\Block\BlockName"
                template="MyCompany_ModulName::template.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The button works alright, but now the Page title is below everything else on the page.

Compare this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F8vd.png

With this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wejTo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the below code into `wishlist_index_index.xml` of your module

```
<move element="mycompany.blockname" destination="customer.wishlist.buttons" after="-"/>
```

Save the file and run below command from your **Magento root**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If still facing any issue feel free to revert back

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Dont't run `setup:upgrade` command every time refer this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Comment: Okay Thank You! `@PrincePatel` I was not aware of this.

Comment: Now my answer is okay??

Comment: Use `static-content:deploy` only if you made changes with __html, css, js, ....__ No need for layout changes. Now it's ok +1 from me

Comment: But then no one will be able to use my module, if part of the installation instruction is "now open that other xml file and add this line at that location".

Comment: Oh, wait, you mean my layout file, not `wishlist_index_index.xml` from the Wishlist module! Yes, that worked, first defining the `<block>` and then `<move>`. But why doesn't it work the other way?

Comment: You always need to do changes into your modules stuffs only never change the default or magentos core files.

Comment: It is working in that way also but may be it is not working here because you are creating a complete new entity into the already present stuff & layout of magento so for that you first need to define your block & then change its location

Comment: Always do accept & upvote if the answer helped you in solving your problem so that it can be useful to others as-well Thank you!