# How to override vendor theme in app/design folder magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, theme, magento2-enterprise, overriding

**We have one project which has a custom theme in vendor folder. Like `vendor/{Vendor}/{custom-theme}/`**

> vendor/{vendorname}/custom-theme/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Vendor/customtheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now I need to **override some files from the custom theme**. So I created theme folder in `app/code/design` as per registation.php

**Override** `vendor/{vendorname}/{custom-theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

**to**

> app/code/design/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

But unfortunately, not working.

I know the one way to override vendor custom theme files, **create and register new theme with a parent vendor custom theme** to make this work.

**But I would like to know if there is any other way to work this without creating another theme?**

**Note:** the Custom theme is developed by previous company and they do not provide composer credentials to update custom theme from the composer. So we must override custom vendor theme to `app/design/frontend`

Comment: After override, you have follow step like php bin/magento setup:upgrade,  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f and all the step

Comment: @KamleshSolanki We need not run `setup:upgrade` command for override files. check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758  For confirmation I already run all commands

Answer (score 0):

There is no way except creating another theme extended from those you need to change in your case.
However you may move theme files from `vendor` folder to `app/code/design` and treat it as your custom theme as well.