# Magento 2:- How to upload image in custom module in admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, adminhtml, uicomponent

Change the mode, then not working image preview got an error `404 image-preview.html`

Developer mode working fine, but production mode not working form page

```
<field name="recipes_image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">recipe</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Dac_Recipes/image-preview</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="recipes/test/upload"/>
            </item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried cache flush and static content deploy?

Comment: Kindly check your pub folder permission is set or not

Answer (score 0):

Run command :

> rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Also, check folder permission and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution.

```
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento cache/clean
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Check pub folder permission.
 Then working fine.

Comment: in your case not need to run: bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: you just need to flush cache and deploy static content and in some case delete `pub/static/*` folders. di compile not require in your case.

Comment: We need not run each command every time. This is really bad practice. Please check this answer for when you should run which command: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758