# Injecting object into a pluigin

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I just want to inject an object into my plugin.

```
/* @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session */
protected $session;

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session)
{
    $this->session = $session;
}
```

For some reason, I get an error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Company\Modul\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Magento\Checkout\Model\Session, none given,
>   called in ...

I've deleted the generate directory, clear the cache, but I am still getting this error.

Why is it?

Comment: Check this for When you should run which command in Magento 2: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `generation/code`

**Run command:**

> bin/magento cache:flush
>
> bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: As I mentioned: _I've deleted the generate directory, clear the cache, but I am still getting this error._

Comment: remove generation/code and run above command

Comment: Hm, it works. Why should I recompile the di in developer mode, when I do not change any xml<

Comment: You should do it when you change anything related to __construct or di.xml

Comment: As a sidenote if your website is in developer mode, it is sufficient to just use 1 command: magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it is technically correct. However you might want to add that he should just switch to developer mode. Also it would be a good idea to be sure that the Apache user has sufficient file permissions to continuously generate those files.