# Magento 2.1.7 Command issuse

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

As when I change in .html file do I need to run setup:upgrade, setup:static-content:deploy and permissions to get changes.

Comment: get your question's answer from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/55928)

Comment: Any other way is there where i don't need to run commands Hit's

Comment: Set developer mode . no need to run command it will deploy content automatically

Comment: if i set Set developer mode website is not loadind giving pub has blocked  Mukesh Prajapati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have changed following / Forntend files:

.html, .phtml , .xml ( layout ), .js, .css

and you are in **default** mode ( to check, **php bin/magento deploy:mode:show** ) then you should run Only following commands to take your changes effect :

`Deploy static content :`
**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

`Flush cache:`
**php bin/magento cache:flush**

if you are in **developer** mode then you don't need to deploy-static-content just flush cache and your changes will take effect.

**NOTE** : if you are using linux then you might need to set permission too. so better way is just change your project folder ownership to www-data:www-data ( default apache user / group )