# Magento 2: why does .gitignore -- ignore all vendor files? M2 Default .gitignore

Tags: git

we are using the Magento default `.gitignore` for development.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/config-reference-gitignore.html

(b.t.w. a similar version can be found here, but I would recommend the original from Magento: https://www.gitignore.io/api/magento2)

**Question**: why is the gitignore ignoring `vendor/*` files that may be installed and containing new/used extensions?

(we found out after installing an extension and wishing to commit the new code)

Appreciate it

References:
[Magento2 - local / staging / production deployment & gitignore](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186524/magento2-local-staging-production-deployment-gitignore)

Comment: Not storing the vendor folder allows you/your developer to run composer update which pulls down the latest versions of the core libraries and any 3rd part extensions. if you dont want to have to keep pushing custom modules into repositiories you can add them under them app/code folder which does get stored within git but its all down to personal preference

Comment: And how bad is it to "inlcude" the /vendor code already. Even if you do run composer update: wont it always check for new code anyways?

Comment: yes but every time you run composer update it will update the code within the vendor folder but not on the repo so everytime u pull from master it will deploy your older version which will cause issues with module versions and code_base version which are defined within the magento database

Comment: I understand. Difficult. But a full update is also not always wanted. So maybe including it sounds good but you should do it after each composer update as a habit. Or create a hook for git commit that ask if you want to execute a composer update prior?

Comment: you can lock your composer file to specific versions, you can also include scripts as part of the update action on composer which will run after a successful update. i never recommend committing vendor bu i can only advise against it if you want to save vendor then that is up to you.

Comment: you can lock your composer file to specific versions, you can also include scripts as part of the update action on composer which will run after a successful update. i never recommend committing vendor bu i can only advise against it if you want to save vendor then that is up to you.

Comment: Deployment to production isn't when I want to be relying on a bunch of random 3rd party downloads/installations to run smoothly (and in a timely fashion). Ignoring /vendor with Git also removes a good check against malicious modifications. I've discovered multiple hacks when running ```git status``` on Magento 1 production sites and finding unexpected changes. In Magento 2, ignoring /vendor means turning a blind eye to a huge portion of the application.