# Magento 2 plugin not calling the around function

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, plugin

I created a small module which has a plugin. 
This plugin must exchange a method with my own.

But my plugin is never being called.

I have been staring at this for a few hours. Can anyone help me with this?

/etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\DataProvider">
        <plugin disabled="false"
                name="Custom_ConfigurableChildSearch_DataProvider"
                sortOrder="10"
                type="Custom\ConfigurableChildSearch\Plugin\DataProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

/Plugin/DataProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\ConfigurableChildSearch\Plugin;

class DataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\DataProvider $subject
     * @param \Closure                                                          $proceed
     *
     * @param                                                                   $indexData
     * @param                                                                   $productData
     * @param                                                                   $storeId
     */
    public function aroundPrepareProductIndex(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\DataProvider $subject, \Closure $proceed, $indexData, $productData, $storeId)
    {
        var_dump('test');
        exit;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Things to try when your plugins aren't being called.

Inserting `die('loaded plugin')` temporarily in your plugin and `die('loaded method')` in the original method (or using debugger breakpoints) is a good idea.

1: Clear the generated files (fast, good for a quick check if your module has already been registered with #2)

```
rm -rf generated/*
```

2: Clear all caches and generated dirs, and register new modules. (slow, but basically refreshes everything)

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

3: Regenerate the di code. (slow, but can find issues in your code that the other methods don't)

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Usually, #1 works, if not, try #2, then #3. If none of those work, check that your module's `di.xml` lines up with your modules (in the original post, it seems to).

Double-check that filepaths correspond with class names, and that case matches.

Official documentation for plugins is here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `setup:di:compile` after defining your plugin?

Take a look at [Magento 2 Docs Code Compiler](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html)

and at: [Magento2 - setup:di:compile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184237/magento2-setupdicompile?rq=1) + [Magento 2: When should I run which commands?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184921/magento-2-when-should-i-run-which-commands/184927#184927)

According to that you have to run that command if you changed something in your di.xml files.