# Why I still need to run setup:di:compile in developer mode?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, dependency-injection, setup-di-compile

**Quick Intro**

I'm working on a payment module and using Magento 2.3.2 (irrelevant).
As stated in many places, we don't need to run `setup:di:compile` when in developer mode (which is my scenario).

> As we know, once you run it for the first time, `generated/code` and
>   `generated/metadata` folders are created and Magento runs in
>   "compiled" mode instead
>   (`\Magento\Framework\App\EnvironmentFactory::getMode`).

However, after deleting these folders, we should get it normal behaviour, and that's what I did.

**The problem**

After updating this payment module and going to checkout (/checkout) I always get an ajax error apparently related to dependency injection.
[image: checkout page]

The error is visible in the html source as follows:

```
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in /Users/martins/www/my-magento2-dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/martins/www/my-magento2-dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer-&gt;create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /Users/martins/www/my-magento2-dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager-&gt;get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /Users/martins/www/my-magento2-dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory-&gt;resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'resource', 'RicardoMartins\\...')
#3 /Users/martins/www/my-magento2-dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManage in <b>/Users/martins/www/my-magento2-dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php</b> on line <b>50</b><br />
```

*Full stack trace available [here](https://pastebin.com/eKSdChQ6)*

Even after `setup:upgrade`, `cache:flush`, `cache:clean`, manual cleanup on common folders, etc, nothing works until I run a `setup:di:compile`.

**Update**: When submitting my module to Magento Marketplace, the QA review got the same problem on Magento 2.2.9 (doesn't happen on 2.3.x). But in 2.2.9 even by running `setup:di:compile` doesn't fix the issue. The problem in this particular case was with the constructor params ([see the changes](https://github.com/r-martins/PagSeguro-Magento-Transparente-M2/pull/18/files)). However, the question still remains for newer versions.

**The question**

So the question is: am I doing something wrong, or despite the documentation and blog posts about this, we still rely on `setup:di:compile` even in developer mode?

**Additional links and references**

1. [Magento Docs: General CLI Installation](https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/install/#enable-the-extension) (where it says Magento doesn't prompt to use setup:di:compile in developer mode)
2. [Github](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/2189) - Issue solving the "problem" to ask running setup:di:compile in dev mode
3. [When you should run di:compile](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2017/07/magento-2-run-setupdicompile/) (blog post from Cadence Labs)

Comment: Exactly my question as well in Magento 2.3, which is annoying. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not mandatory to run setup:di:compile command everytime but if you have done any code change specially with factory methods ,proxy, add plugins or any code compilation then you must need to run this command.

Please Review reference like.

Getting [Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184334)

Answer (score 1):

The Command:
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

This command does not need to be run when the app is in Developer mode. Magento uses automatic code generation when the app is in this mode, and if it can’t find a generated class it creates it on the fly.

In Production mode, this command should run each time the changes have been made especially related to PHP.

Resource and more info: https://support.serverguy.com/portal/kb/articles/magento-2-bin-magento-setup-di-compile

Comment: That's what the documentation says, but as you can see in the example in the question, it's not what happens. The error only goes away when I run the command, even in developer mode.

Comment: Yeah nice theoretical answer. Everyone who worked with Magento 2 knows this is just theory. In practice, it doesn't apply all the time. The question of @ricardo still remains.